# Rails responds to angular resource.get with html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4 is responding to an angular resource.get request with HTML, and I can't figure out why.

The javascript is

```
$resource("/questions/:id", {id: "@id"}}.get({id: 16});
```

The server is failing because it can't find the HTML view for that request.

```
Missing template questions/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

If I point my browser to `/querstions/16.json` it responds as expected with the JSON.

Is there something missing from the request headers?

If I look at the headers, the request seems to have the right request headers to trigger ruby to respond with json...

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/questions/16
Request Method:GET

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:amazing_earth.dev
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:3000/demo
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: if you are looking for a `.json` file shouldn't you point at that file?

Comment: so, do you have a template for questions/show?

Comment: @charlietfl previous rails applications I've built have responded based on the request format requested by XHR so I'm curious why this one is requiring me to be explicit.

Comment: @enchante Nope, HTML template not needed because I don't want to respond to html, and it renders json fine without a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue of rails for quite long time, check [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9940)

According to the comments [there](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9940#issuecomment-115412352), this issue has been fix in the newest rails version.

And if you don't want to modify the angularjs header, just change the default format for the api route

```
get 'questions/:id', to: 'questions#show', defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into upgrading to 4.2.1, I'm on 4.2 so hopefully it's rather painless

Comment: I updated to 4.2.1, no change, still getting a response in the wrong format